# Converting CGRect from UIImage to rect in UIScrollView in order to perform zoom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIScrollView which contains a UIImageView

I need to zoom to a specific location **relative** to the UIImage and **NOT** the UIScrollView

So for example I have a UIImage where the size is 1000,1000 PX

I would like to zoom to a square such that CGRect = (400,500,100,100) inside that image

Unfortunately self.scrollView zoomToRect:animated isn't working properly because this rect is outside of its view and not in the same coordinate system

Also the aspect ratio of the UIImage can change inside of the UIImageview so it can be difficult to calculate its offset inside of the UIImageView (the black bars at the top and bottom of the image)

I know about

convertRect:fromView:

so thought about doing

```
-(void)zoomToRectInImage:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect rect1 = [self.imageView.image convertRect:rect fromView:self.imageView.image]; // error because UIImage isn't a view

    CGRect scrollViewRect = [self.scrollView convertRect:rect1 fromView:self.imageView];

   [self.scrollView zoomToRect:scrollViewRect animated:YES]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question in a different format and this might help out someone

[UIScrollView how to zoomToRect in UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508167/uiscrollview-how-to-zoomtorect-in-uiimageview)