# UIScrollView how to zoomToRect in UIImageView

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to perform `self.scrollview zoomToRect:animated` 
such that the `rect` is relative to the `UIImage` and not the `UIImageView` embedded inside that `scrollView`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was converting the coordinates from the `UIImage` to the `UIScrollView`

[This library](https://github.com/nubbel/UIImageView-GeometryConversion) helped a lot.

so added a method in my class

```
-(void)zoomToRectInImage:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect r        = [self.imageView convertRectFromImage:rect];
    CGRect zoomrect = [self convertRect:r fromView:self.imageView];
    [self zoomToRect:zoomrect animated:YES];
}
```